# Spring boot: cannot return index page instead of error page not found

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am building web application using spring boot for backend and angular2 for frontend, spring boot return whitelabel page if a none root url was accessed (because the servlet container does not know about the angular routing), so I am trying to replace the whitelabel page with the index.html page.

After reading some article about this i tried this but not working

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean
 implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {        
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
}
}
```

index.html is placed under src/main/resources/static

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works perfectly fine to display `index.html` page (instead of white label error), but you need to ensure that your `CustomizationBean` is available for scanning for the Spring container during the start up `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.yourproject"})`

> As far as I know, in spring boot the scan is automatic , I have my
>   CustomizationBean annotation with @Component.

Spring boot, by default only scans the classes under the `myproject` packages (where `ApplicationLauncher` `main` class resides) as explained in this doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html). The rest of the packages need to be specified in `@ComponentScan`

Comment: im using spring boot, does not take care of this?

Comment: Actually I put a break point on the line where the error page is added and that line is getting executed

Comment: If your `Component` exists inside the main launcher class package, it will take care, otherwise you need to add `@ComponentScan`

Comment: As far as I know, in spring boot the scan is automatic , I have my CustomizationBean annotation with @Component, should not this be enought, anyway I moved the class to the package of the main launcher class and the same